# php regexp to split chinese text by character

Tags: php, regex

For example, I have the following string in request from client:

```
我学习中国的语言, 国的语言.
```

I want to get an array of characters including spaces, commas, dots etc, so basically I need this broken down by character like this:

```
$characters = [
    "我", "学", "习", "中", "国", "的", "语", "言", ",", " ", "国", "的","语","言"
]
```

I presume I need to use some multibyte functions since Chinese characters can occupy 3 or more bytes. What regexp expression can I use to get that array?

Comment: Use one of the [Unicode character categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all('~.~u', $str, $match);
```

`.` matches any character but not of line breaks. But the same `.` would match any character even line breaks when the `s` DOTALL modifier is used. Since your input contain Unicode characters, you must need to enable the `u` modifier.

**OR**

Through `preg_split`

```
$str = "我学习中国的语言, 国的语言.";
$split = preg_split('~(?<=.)(?=.)~u', $str);
print_r($split);
```

**Example:**

```
$str = "我学习中国的语言, 国的语言.";
preg_match_all('~.~u', $str, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 我
            [1] => 学
            [2] => 习
            [3] => 中
            [4] => 国
            [5] => 的
            [6] => 语
            [7] => 言
            [8] => ,
            [9] =>  
            [10] => 国
            [11] => 的
            [12] => 语
            [13] => 言
            [14] => .
        )

)
```

Comment: i've [try](http://codepad.org/0LiJjGkm) but `Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: this version of PCRE is not compiled with PCRE_UTF8`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, thanks a lot! I use the following option for English text `preg_split('/regexp here/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)`. Is the solution you presented will produce the same output with regard to flags I use in `preg_split`?

Comment: or like this: `preg_split('~(?!^|$)~u', $str)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, thanks! Do you mean I don't need to use them for chinese version or English version?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, it seems that it doesn't include line breaks into array, is it expected behavior? because I need them included. I used `preg_split('~(?<=.)(?=.)~u', $str);` option

Comment: try `'~(?s)(?<=.)(?=.)~u'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, yeah, this one works! Thanks! Best of luck!